# I was trying to rvm install 3.0.4 on my ubuntu 22.04 it started installation and the got to point it through errors listed below, How can I fit it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rvm

Error running '__rvm_package_extract /usr/share/rvm/archives/ruby-3.0.4.tar.gz /usr/share/rvm/tmp/rvm_src_9',
please read /usr/share/rvm/log/1656752587_ruby-3.0.4/extract.log
There has been an error while trying to extract the source. Halting the installation.
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.